# How do I add or save new lines in a textarea box with php?

Tags: php, javascript, textarea, newline

For example here is my text etc.

now here is the newline.

How do I create that new line in php I normal need to hold Ctrl and Enter to create it it this textarea box?

Does it require javascript?

Comment: And how does this relate to MySQL?

Comment: can you be more specific? you have a textarea an you want to?
If you want to insert some text, use enter to go to the next row, save the $_REQUEST['textareaName'] without nl2br() in the database, when loading, just echo the var in the <textarea><? echo $var;?></textarea>

Answer (score 3):

if you want to set the default text of a textarea you don't need php. You just need to set its value attribute with something as "Your text.\nAnother line", where '\n' will get replaced by a new line. Alternatevely you can do it through Javascript if you set the attribute dynamically, as in:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_your_textarea").value = "Your text\nAnew line";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use so-called "escape sequence". You can find list of all escape sequences on [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). Escape sequences only work in strings in double quotes.

```
$string = "My string\nWith a line breaks\ninserted"; // notice the \n
$no_escapes = 'This will not replace \n with a line break';
```

Comment: I used the PHP function nl2br() to accomplish this task thank you for the answer though!

Comment: @Matthew: That's probably wrong. Within a textbox, newlines are actual newlines, not HTML paragraph breaks (`<br />`).